# Appdelegate Variable in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I used to declare variale in appdelegate and make it as sharable in all the classes (If the variable is global ) .

```
appDelegate = (StoryAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

this was the code am using normally to access appdelegate variable. Now am trying a story board application and its not working for me . while declaring appdelegate it shows an error "Unknown type name StoryAppDelegate".

```
StoryAppDelegate*ss;
```

this is the code am using .

Any help appreciated .

Comment: `#import "StoryAppDelegate.h"`. And **use whitespace.** Your code is **ugly.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a singleton instance of your global variable as they have bailed me out of your exact situation multiple times. Here is an example I'm currently using to implement a singleton. This methodology is also ARC-safe as well

mySingleton.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface mySingleton : NSObject {

}
+ (NSMutableDictionary *) myMutableDict;

@end
```

mySingleton.m

```
#import "mySingleton.h"

@implementation mySingleton

+ (NSMutableDictionary *)myMutableDict
{
    static NSMutableDictionary *singletonInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        singletonInstance = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    });
    return singletonInstance;
}

@end
```

As long as you include mySingleton.h in all of your view controllers you can access the data via `[mySingleton myMutableDict]`. For example: `[[mySingleton myMutableDict] setObject:myObject forKey:myKey];` This will of course work with any object type.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use the app delegate. That isn't what it's for.

Instead, create a specific class to own the responsibility + knowledge, make it a singleton and have all classes that require it get it via it's 'sharedController' (or whatever you call it) class method.

Or use a 'constants' file with a static variable or something (just not the app delegate).

Answer (score 1):

Storyboard is used only for design, not changes to the code.

For that, you'd use:

```
AppDelegate *app;
```

in the header file of the view's controller.

And in the implementation file,

```
  app=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

Then you can just use app.yourVariable

Answer (score 0):

It seems the case of circular dependency.

use `@class StoryAppDelegate;`

instead of

```
#import "StoryAppDelegate.h"
```

in your header file.